# how to force to use the com.google.android.gms:play-services:15.0.0

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, resolutionstrategy

having an app which has dependency on a lib,  that lib has dependency:

```
api "com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.0.2"
```

in this app it wants to use `com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.0.1`,
so it did these is gradle:

```
implementation ('com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.0.1') { force = true }
```

which triggers the download and also

```
configurations.all {
resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
    def requested = details.requested

    if (details.requested.group == 'com.google.android.gms' && requested.name.contains('play-services-maps')) {
        details.useVersion "15.0.1"
    }

    /*
    // this causes build error that cannot relsove the xxx-15.0.0
    //
    if (requested.name.contains('play-services')
            && VersionNumber.parse(requested.version) < VersionNumber.parse(15.0.0)
        ) {
        details.useVersion "15.0.0"
    }
    */
}
}
```

in the dependency graph, it shows:

```
dogfoodRuntimeClasspath - Dependencies for runtime/packaging
```

+--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.0.1@aar

But at runtime still crashes at where it reference to `LatLng`

```
NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/android/gms/maps/model/LatLng
```

which is from `play-services-maps:15.0.1`

Question 1:
Why is that, and how to force to use the 15.0.1 version?

2:
Seems since no one is having dependency on `"com.google.android.gms:play-services:15.0.0"`, the part:

```
/*
// this causes build error that cannot relsove the xxx-15.0.0
//
if (requested.name.contains('play-services')
        && VersionNumber.parse(requested.version) < VersionNumber.parse(15.0.0)
    ) {
    details.useVersion "15.0.0"
}
*/
```

will find the requested.version==11.0.2 and try to replace with 15.0.0, but that will cause failure that cannot resolve the play-service-xxx:15.0.0.

Is it because the `resolutionStrategy` only replace the version number but will not download the files?